# Laravel ORM count() not working proprerly with groupBy()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

I want to count city owners in my database. City table is like this structure:

```
(int) id | (int) player_id | (int) game_id
```

I have model `City` and try to execute next code:

```
\App\City::where('game_id', $game_id) // $game_id was delivered earlier
         ->groupBy('player_id')
         ->count()
```

This code returns me value **3**. It's wrong value so I get code from `DB::getQueryLog()`. Query is next:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `cities` where `game_id` = ? and `cities`.`deleted_at` is null group by `player_id`
```

When I execute this query in PMA I get **2** (valid value).

I don't know why my code not working. I tried also to execute not `count()` but `count('player_id')` - not working too.

It's strange but when I use `get()` method I have collection with **2!** objects. What do I wrong?

Comment: `cities`.`deleted_at` is null, ok thats fine. could you do deleted_at = ''.

Comment: @Plum I don't have any solf deleted objects, so result of this query is 0 rows :)

Comment: have you tried with full query like db->query("select .......") without using the short forms ->where()->groupby() etc..

Comment: @Plum When I execute `\DB::select('...')` this method returns an array, something like this: `[{"count(*)": 1}, {"count(*)": 2}]`

Comment: 1. There is no `player_id` in the schema that you shown. 2. can you post data that you have in your table that should lead to a valid result?

Comment: @peterm my fault, it's `player_id`, not `owner_id` - it's typo. But it still not working.

Comment: Are the bindings in the correct order? Check with: $query = \App\City::where('game_id', $game_id)->groupBy('player_id'); $query->getBindings() and $query->getRawBindings()

Comment: I've had this problem recently as well.  This was working before, and now it seems that the count is not counting the individual models, but something in the group.  I have relegated my code to ->get() and then counting the models inside.  Stupid inefficient, but at least I know I get the right number for now.